# Access the only property in an object in IE8+

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a object that is parsed from `JSON`, and it always contains only one property but the name of this property (i.e. the key name) changes for each `JSON` msg.

In IE9+ and other modern browsers, I can use:

```
value = msg[Object.keys(msg)[0]];
```

to access the value of this property. However, IE8 does  not support `keys`, so what is a fully compatible way of accessing the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define such a function :

```
function getVal(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) return obj[key];
}
```

and then do

```
value = getVal(msg);
```

Comment: Beware of extending the Object prototype if you do this. Make it work with Object.prototype being extended and I'll upvote.